# Google contact api returns Invalid XML Document error

Tags: google-contacts-api

While adding contacts using google contacts api, I have been getting status code 400, with Invalid XML Document error.

If I remove the following line the add contact api succeeds. However, this behaviour is not what I want. I would like to add it to the base group 6.

```xml
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false"
          href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/binthi123@gmail.com/base/6"/>
```

The following is the body of the add new contact api post request:

```xml
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>1234567890</gd:givenName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile" primary="true">
    ${phone_number}
  </gd:phoneNumber>
  <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/binthi123@gmail.com/base/6" />
</atom:entry>
```

Comment: have you tried adding `xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008"` to `atom:entry` tag?

Comment: Same is happening to me. Seems like google has just changed something in the API without updating the docs... Have you found a solution? The gContact:groupMembershipInfo has worked for years until a few hours ago. @barbsan the addition of `xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008"` does not solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem changing the tag  `<gContact:groupMembershipInfo>`in `<gd:groupMembershipInfo>` , so any tag with `<gContact`> no longer works but only with `<gd:>`, this only when you create new contact if you update there isn't any problem

Comment: Worked perfectly. Suggested that this be the accepted answer. How did you find the solution John?

Comment: Hi @MilkMan, for logical deduction because I've two function one for create new contact and another one for update , the problem was only in the first one ,so removing one tag at a time I've found that the problem was on <Gcontact:> tag and then I've tried to subsitute with <gd:> and was ok,but on Google guide hasn't been updated.

Comment: @JohnJ I applied above solution but it's still not working for me.
Can you help me ?

Comment: just change the opening tag to <gd:groupMembershipInfo> only? what about the ending tag does it required </gd:groupMembershipInfo> as well?

Answer (score 2):

Our team ran into a variant of this problem where the Contacts API was returning "Invalid JSON" 400 error when posting a new contact (via XML).  The problem was related to us setting the alt=json parameter; apparently there is a bug on Google's end that gets invoked if you ask for a JSON response from that method.